# Get numpy to perform consistent error reporting on truncating numerical conversions

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I've noticed that numpy arrays values are truncated when a narrowing conversion is performed. In my case this is expected behavior.

Problem is that sometimes the conversion doesn't happen and a runtime exception is raised.

Anybody know how to get consistent truncation or error behavior when a numpy array performs a narrowing conversions?

Consider these experiments

1. expected & fits

```
    np.asarray([(2**64)-1],np.dtype("u8"))
    array([18446744073709551615], dtype=uint64)
```

2. expected & truncated

```
    np.asarray([(2**64)-1],np.dtype("u4")) 
    array([4294967295], dtype=uint32)
```

3. unexpected & runtime error... (also not converting to C long)

```
    np.asarray([(2**64)-1],np.dtype("u2"))
    *** OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

4. unexpected & runtime error... (also not converting to C long)

```
    np.asarray([(2**64)-1],np.dtype("u1"))
    *** OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Anyway to get the `u1` and `u2` cases to behave like `u4`?

Comment: Somewhat related: [#1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12513) [#2](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19122). You'll probably have to handle incompatible values yourself.